# Get Current Activity Context in a non activity class

Tags: android-activity, android-context

I have an application in android which has no. of activity. Now I needed that the context of currently running activity in a non-activity class. How can I get that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Application` class :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static Context context;
private static Activity activity;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public synchronized static Context getAppContext() {
    return MyApplication.context;
}

/**
 * setCurrentActivity(null) in onPause() on each activity 
 * setCurrentActivity(this) in onResume() on each activity
 * 
 */

public static void setCurrentActivity(Activity currentActivity) {
    activity = currentActivity;
}

public static Activity currentActivity() {
    return activity;
}

}
```

Comment: This "solution" is introducing several bugs in your application, including: memory leak and wrong references. Always take the control to the current activity. There are many techniques to track activity transitions (or fragments transactions). The main problem here is because you are using static variables to hold instances that you know that will be invalid at any time.

Comment: That's why I wrote a comment in the code saying set current activity to null in onPause and set it again in onResume

Comment: I thinks this solution is valid. Anybody else try it and getting issues with this solution.

Comment: without changing the code in the activity how do we get the current running activity in the application?

Comment: What about when you are already extending a class (like ContentProvider)?